# Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Switching from light to dark mode using cookies (Nextjs, Mui5)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

When the browser loads if the cookie (darkMode) is set to OFF the light mode is on but when The cookie (darkMode) is set to ON which means the dark is on the browser does load the dark mode but only for the navbar and seems that it stops the rendering process and the warning happens I am using it with material ui switch.

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
  darkMode: Cookies.get('darkMode') === 'ON' ? true : false,
}

export const DarkModeSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'darkMode',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    toggleDarkMode: (state) => {
      let newDarkMode = !state.darkMode;
      Cookies.set("darkMode", newDarkMode ? "ON" : "OFF");
      state.darkMode = newDarkMode
    }
  },
})

export const { toggleDarkMode } = DarkModeSlice.actions

export default DarkModeSlice.reducer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This video explains how to switch from dark to light using next-themes form npm watch it if there are some errors and there will be, come back and continue reading my instructions

[Dark Mode Persistence with Next.js is Harder than with plain React (MUI example)](https://youtu.be/kIkdoW6VUIQ)

**INSTRUCTIONS**

Please Do not forget to remove the `<CssBaseline />` under the theme provider or PageProvider if you are gonna follow the video because next-themes that you will download form npm is gonna do every thing for you. also add key attribute if you are using switch component. Follow The code below.

```
import { useTheme } from "next-themes";

const { theme, resolvedTheme, setTheme } = useTheme();

const [isDark, setIsDark] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  resolvedTheme === "light" ? setIsDark(false) : setIsDark(true);
  return () => {};
}, [resolvedTheme]);

<Switch
   key={isDark}
   checked={isDark}
   onChange={() =>
     setTheme(resolvedTheme === "light" ? "dark" : "light")
   }
/>
```

Copy and Paste it, it is gonna work in the component you wanna use the switch in, If any one still could not solve it please feel free to contact me.